# GWT client - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear_31_g$' of undefined

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I am new to GWT and trying to create a small application. I am currently assembling a small framework for the app, a generic layout handler, etc. This may not be the last problem I will bump into, but I just cannot find any solution to this on google.

So I have a class type, which return me Composites. Also, I have another one, which stores these kind of classes in Stack (I also tried Vector, I thought maybe GWT has issues with it). It didn't matter. If I call the .clear method on the Stack, I have the aforementioned error in the inspection menu of Chrome:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear_31_g$' of undefined

Like if GWT does not know, how to convert this method to javascript or what? Do you know what is the problem here?

eclipse neon, Java 7 setting on Java SDK 1.8 (maybe this?), GWT 2.7.0 and App Engine 1.9.34

Thanks!

edit1: I also found the page, which contains the emulated JRE classes' list (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) with all supported methods. Now I see, that clear is not on that list for Stack, but empty does and that gives me the same error. :-/

Comment: You call `clear` method on `null`.

Comment: Ah jeez, that was it. Even the error message is descriptful but I just couldn't see through it. Thanks!

p.s. maybe you should write it into the answer sheet and I could push an accept it.

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer. I hope it will help others too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error simply means that you try to call the `clear()` method on a `null` object (the object is `undefined`).

The error message itself is not as clear as it could be. First, it's not always about reading a property but also about calling a method. Second, remember that you run a compiled to javascript code and the property (or method) name may differ from the original one - it has something like `_31_g$` added in the runtime.

Comment: "First, it's not always about reading a property but also about calling a method" - so if I was calling a method, which is in JavaSE for the given class, but it does not supported by the JRE emulation (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html), then I would get the same error?

And thanks for the help, that was the problem.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) And I meant that the error message could differentiate both situations and be `Cannot call method ... of undefined` or `Cannot read property ... of undefined`.
If you call a method that is not supported by JRE emulation you will get an error like that `The method lineSeparator() is undefined for the type System` error.
If you use a class that is not in JRE emulation you will get `No source code is available for type ...` error (for example java.awt.Color class).